# Spring Data JPA - How to persist nested object any existing or not

Tags: java, spring-boot, orm, spring-data-jpa, spring-data

Using Springboot 2.4.0, I am trying to develop a simple module to manage a tipical relationship between the entities `Product` and `Order` (ManyToMany relationship).

In Order, I have this `products` field:

```
@ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
@JoinTable(
        name="products_orders",
        joinColumns=@JoinColumn(name="order_id"),
        inverseJoinColumns=@JoinColumn(name="product_id")
)
private List<Product> products;
```

Since I don't need it, for now I am omitting an `orders` field in the `Product` entity.

Previous to this relationship, I have a CRUD for `Product` entity up and properly running, so I can insert products through a Product Repository:

```
public interface ProductRepository extends JpaRepository<Product, Integer>
```

I need to place an order with a number of products within it. I have this code:

```
List<Products> myListOfProducts = new ArrayList<>();

myListOfProducts.add(previouslyExistingProduct);
myListOfProducts.add(nonExistingProduct);

Order myorder = new Order(myListOfProducts, "mail", LocalDateTime.now());
myorder.save();
```

The question is: is it possible to get with the previous code that the new order gets saved as well as the products linked to it (saving both the existing and non existing products)?

This is the Order Repository:

```
public interface OrderRepository extends JpaRepository<Order, Integer>
```

This is what I got so far:

- If I change CascadeType to `CascadeType.MERGE`, I get to link only existing products to the new order, but for new Products, I get this error:

> org.hibernate.TransientObjectException: object references an unsaved transient instance - save the transient instance before flushing: com.gallelloit.productcrud.model.Product; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: org.hibernate.TransientObjectException: object references an unsaved transient instance - save the transient instance before flushing: com.gallelloit.productcrud.model.Product

- Any other value I put to CascadeType (including `CascadeType.ALL`), I get the opposite: new products are saved and linked to the new order, but for existing products, I get this error:

> detached entity passed to persist:
> com.gallelloit.productcrud.model.Product; nested exception is
> org.hibernate.PersistentObjectException: detached entity passed to
> persist: com.gallelloit.productcrud.model.Product

I know that I can do it "manually" getting each of the products, and saving them before the `order.save()`, but I was wondering if Spring Data did it for you.

Any idea?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Relying on `CascadeType.MERGE` is not safe in this context, because it updates the associated `Product`s as well, meaning you may unintentionally overwrite existing `Product` data.

You can optimize the fetching of existing products by asking JPA to create proxies for the existing entities instead of actually fetching their associated state from the DB. This can be done using `JpaRepository.getOne()`. You'll need sth like:

```
order.setProducts(order.getProducts()
    .map(product -> product.getId() == null ? productRepository.save(product) : productRepository.getOne(product.getId())
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

If you decide on using `CascadeType.PERSIST` or `CascadeType.ALL`, you can of course replace `productRepository.save(product)` with just `product`. `CascadeType.ALL` doesn't make sense for `@ManyToMany`, though, since it implies `CascadeType.REMOVE`, which you *most certainly* don't want.

Also, I'm assuming the logic of saving the order happens inside a transactional context, right?

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Where would that code be placed? I guess that in the OrderService, right? That is a good solution. Only two doubts. A less important one: it makes me inject the productRepository in the OrderServiceImpl class. This is not big deal... but I hadn't done it so far and now I have to. No big deal as I said. The other one is: what any product does not exist and getOne method returns a null? Will I be inserting a null value in the list? What will be the behavior? Will I have to handle this possibility "manually"?

Comment: An error in this question: "The other one is: what any product does not exist and getOne method returns a null?" It should say: "The other one is: what IF any product does not exist and getOne method returns a null?"

Comment: `getOne` never returns `null`. JPA doesn't check the existence of the entity when using `getOne`, that's the whole point - to avoid an extra query. If it turns out that the id doesn't point to a valid row in the `PRODUCT` table, you'll get an integrity constraint violation from the DB, though

Comment: Perfect then. I end up performing some validations in the order.setProducts in a similar way to what you explained. One last question: the proxies JPA creates respond to the Proxy Design Pattern? Or what kind of proxies JPA creates? Could you refer some article for me to get a little knowledge on them? Thanks a lot!!

Comment: The best reference is probably the [Hibernate docs](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.2/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#pc-get-reference). And yes, it follows the proxy pattern, in the sense that if you try to access its data, it will get loaded and returned, and so the proxy will be mostly transparent for your app